# When is the dereferencing operator useful?

Tags: c, pointers, operators

I am a newbie c-coder, so this probably has a very simple answer. I understand the function of pointers and the dereferencing operator, but I'm not sure when they're actually useful?

Basic example:

```
  int x = 10;
  int *p;
  p = &x;
  printf(" x = %d", *p);
  printf(" x = %d", x);
    // both print out: x = 10
```

When would dereferencing a pointer be more efficient than addressing the variable directly? Struggling to find good examples (that I can understand) online atm, I appreciate any help.

Comment: *"When would dereferencing a pointer be more efficient than addressing the variable directly?"* - when you only have the access to the pointer, but not the variable.

Comment: The whole point of pointers is that they can refer to different variables. So you can't use the variable directly.

Comment: If you have to handle, i.e. pass to a function, a large structure or any large object you can pass simply its pointer. When an object is created dynamically you have only a pointer. And so on...

Comment: Simple heuristic: don't use pointers unless you need them.  If you don't see a need then you're all good doing without.

Comment: Consider the situation where there is no `x`. Then you must use `*p`. There would be no `x` if the memory was allocated using `malloc`, for example. So why would you do that? So many reasons! Maybe you want to memory allocation to outlast the call of the function that allocates it. Maybe you want to allocate variable amount of memory. Maybe you want to option of changing the size of the memory block you allocate later. etc. etc.

Comment: There's another of use of dereferencing that's *extremely* common: `a[i]` is short for `*(a+i)`. So dereferencing is also used whenever you index an array.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are often used in situations where you need to point to different variables based on dynamic conditions.

For instance, here's an example where the choice of variable is random.

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
int *p;
if (rand() < 0.5) {
    p = &x;
} else {
    p = &y;
}
printf("Chosen value = %d", *p);
```

Answer (score 0):

A time in actual code that the unary * operator  is useful is when you are given a pointer-to-pointer to something. In that situation it is very often necessary to explicitly dereference the first level pointer in order to gain access to the second level pointer (even if that second level is a pointer to a struct and you use the -> member-access operator).

```
struct foo
{
  int x;
}
...
struct foo ** ptr = ...;
(*ptr)->x = 1;
```

And note that the parenthesis in "(*ptr)->x" are needed because -> has higher precedence than *, so without it would be parsed as *(ptr->x) = 1; and fail type checking.